# Creating an input for a customizable keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a visual C# application, and I want to include some options in *my application's preferences* for customization of keyboard shortcuts using some sort of text box input. I understand how to record keyboard input, and how to save it to the user application settings, but I can not find any input controls that have this functionality.

I.e. something like this:

[image]

But using windows forms (Note: The above is from Divvy for OS X from the app store).

Is there any built-in functionality to handle this?
Are there any good libraries or custom inputs I could use?

Otherwise, any suggestions on how to go about implementing something like this?

***Solution:***

Using Bas B's answer and some other logic:

```
private void fShortcut_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
    {
        Keys modifierKeys = e.Modifiers;
        Keys pressedKey = e.KeyData ^ modifierKeys; //remove modifier keys

        if (modifierKeys != Keys.None && pressedKey != Keys.None)
        {
            //do stuff with pressed and modifier keys
            var converter = new KeysConverter();
            fShortcut.Text = converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
            //At this point, we know a one or more modifiers and another key were pressed
            //modifierKeys contains the modifiers
            //pressedKey contains the other pressed key
            //Do stuff with results here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        fShortcut.Text = "";
    }
}
```

The above is a way to tell when a valid shortcut combination is entered by checking if both modifier keys, and another key is pressed.

Comment: Are you looking for keyboard shortcuts for VS2010 or for your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the user enter the preferred shortcut in a TextBox, then handle the KeyDown event, for instance:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys modifierKeys = e.Modifiers;

        Keys pressedKey = e.KeyData ^ modifierKeys; //remove modifier keys

        //do stuff with pressed and modifier keys
        var converter = new KeysConverter();
        textBox1.Text = converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);
}
```

Edit: Updated to include Stecya's answer.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. I used this, along with some other logic, to get the job done. I'll update the question with the final solution.